# Convert black to white in scanned PDF

Tags: pdf, scanning

I have scanned many pages on a scanner with scan type set to 300 dpi black and white text and output format set to PDF. Unfortunately, a great deal of the pages were from a book and there is a shadow on the scanned pages. I wonder if there is any possibility to make the black area (which I marked with blue stripes below) automatically, with a function in Adobe PDF or any other software, white. In the red circle below, there is some text that spans from the black to the white background. This text I would like to be all black and appear on white background.

[image: scanned example page]

Comment: I don't think that this can be done easily. As you have scanned in black&white mode there is no way to distinguish between black shadow pixels and black text pixels.

Comment: @Robert I'm afraid so. However, this should be possible, especially when remembering that we deal with a large black connected area. Text pixels are not connected with that many other black pixels. Therefore, I hoped (and still hope) that there are some simple tool that does this.

Comment: And what about the white text pixels inside the large black connected area. They can be distinguished, since they are inside the large black connected area. They are _surrounded_ by the large black connected area.

Comment: Then where is the problem? Extract the image from the PDF file and use an image editor for editing the extracted JPG file.

Comment: @Robert I hope that there are some existing tools that perform the action directly on the PDF. I have scanned around 1 000 pages with this problem and I am afraid it would take an enormous amount of time to fix all the pages with a simple image editor.